# Is it possible for a class template to receive a class to print its members?

Tags: c++, templates

I usually write the `operator<<` in the `A` class but I was wondering if I could make a `B` template class that could do this for me.

```cpp
class A {
    long a;
    string b;
    int c;

public:
    A(long a, string b) : a(a), b(move(b)), c(c) {}
};
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
class B {
    T foo;

public:
    // this should print all the members of T
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& obj);
};
```

Comment: No, that would require reflection. You can't do that in c++ yet.

Comment: Not in standard C++. What is the problem you want to solve? Debugging?